# Зависимость 2-ух <select> друг от друга

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть select

```
<select id="one">
     <option value="1">one</option>
     <option value="2">two</option>
     <option value="3">three</option>
     <option value="4">four</option>
</select>
```

И есть второй select

```
<select id="one">
     <option value="5">1</option>
     <option value="6">2</option>
     <option value="7">3</option>
     <option value="8">4</option>
</select>
```

Как динамически изменить значение 2 select, при выборе первого, например при выборе One > 3, Two > 1 и т.д.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var sel1 = document.querySelector('#one'),
    sel2 = document.querySelector('#two');

function giveSelection(selValue) {
    if ('2' === selValue)
      sel2.value = '6';

}

giveSelection(sel1.value);
```

```html
<select id="one" onchange="giveSelection(this.value)">
     <option value="1">one</option>
     <option value="2">two</option>
     <option value="3">three</option>
     <option value="4">four</option>
</select>


<select id="two">
     <option value="5">1</option>
     <option value="6">2</option>
     <option value="7">3</option>
     <option value="8">4</option>
</select>
```